# Bluetooth connectivity using MVVMCross

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to ask if the Bluetooth plugin developed by Stuart Lodge  in https://github.com/slodge/BallControl can also be used for normal peer to peer connectivity between two android devices. If not, can you please suggest a decent mono android API for BT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the basic approach in that plugin could be adapted for perr-to-pee seial port communications.

Alternatively, Xamarin have published a chat sample based on the Java one at http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/BluetoothChat/